# What do the properties "@labels" and "@networkNode" mean, and how do I know what code is executed?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm using the INET project in the OMNeT++ simulation framework, and I don't understand what properties are for, and where the corresponding code can be found. Here's an example (from [`inet/src/inet/node/inet/INetworkNode.ned`](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/node/inet/INetworkNode.ned))

```
moduleinterface INetworkNode{
    parameters:
        @display("bgb=,448");
        @networkNode;
        @labels(node,ethernet-node,wireless-node);
    ...
}
```

What do these properties, `@display`, `@networkNode`, `@labels` mean, what are they used for, and how do I find the corresponding source code?

Answer (score 2):

`@networkNode` is the property used by `INET` to recognize topology of a network as well as to decide whether an element should obtain a network address. This property is checked in `_isNetworkNode()` method form `ModuleAccess.cc` and in `extractByProperty()` from `Topology.cc`.

---

The meaning of `@labels` property is descibed in `INET Manual`:

> The `@labels` property can be added to modules and gates, and it allows the OMNeT++ graphical
>   editor to provide better editing experience.

`@labels` property is especially useful for gates because it allows to choose right gate during connecting two elements in editor. According to `INET Manual`:

> If you connect two modules in the editor, the gate selection menu will list
>   gate pairs that have a label in common.

`INET Manual` can be found in `doc` directory of `INET` package.

Comment: How exactly are properties matched to code? Is the `getProperties` mechanism used in `ModuleAccess` the only way, or is there some convention for defining new properties? I tried to look for this in the OMNet++ documentation of the .ned language, but I didn't manage to find the answer.

Comment: `ModuleAccess` is part of `INET`, therefore it is not mentioned in `OMNeT++` manual. `ModuleAccess` uses `getProperties()` as well as `getAsBool()` methods.

Comment: Right, but the manual does mention several core properties [in chapter 3](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:properties), and the [properties section in the NED Reference](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-ref:properties), so I thought there might be some more exhaustive documentation and/or conventions from the OMNeT++ side that are not necessarily exclusive to INET (e.g., some of it might apply to VEINS and other packages). Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Indeed, there is no place in documentation or command where you can get all the supported properties. In NED, OMNeT++ recognizes these: `@class, @display, @unit, @namespace, @network, @enum, @directIn, @loose, @prompt, @signal, @statistic, @property.` The message compiler also understands a lot of other properties that will be greatly expended in OMNeT++ 5.3 (look into src/sim/sim_std.msg and src/nedxml/msgcompiler.cc)